# Example of a cancellative power semigroup

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, monoid

Let $ \, S \, $ be a semigroup such that $ \ |S| \geq 2 \ $. Its power semigroup is the power set $ \, \wp(S) \, $ together with the binary operation
$$XY = \{ xy \in S : x \in X, \ y \in Y \} \ \ .$$

I am interested in the semigroup $ \ Q_S = \wp(S) \setminus \{ \varnothing \} \ $, which I also call the power semigroup of $ \, S \, $.

A semigroup $ \, S \, $ is said *left cancellative* if, and only if, for all $ \ x,y,z \in S \ $, if $ \ xy=xz \ $, then $ \ y=z \ $.

A semigroup $ \, S \, $ is said *right cancellative* if, and only if, for all $ \ x,y,z \in S \ $, if $ \ yx=zx \ $, then $ \ y=z \ $.

> I would like to see an example of a semigroup $ \, S \, $ such that $ \, Q_S \, $ is left cancellative and right cancellative.

I tested the most immediate and the most standard examples of semigroups, but none of them resulted in such a desired example. I don't know where to look anymore.

Comment: Which examples did you try?

Comment: @Shaun $ \, \mathbb{N} \, $, $ \, \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \} \, $, the free semigroups and the multiplicative $ \ S = \{ 0,1,x \} \ $, with $ \ |S|=3 \ $ and $ \ x^2=x \ $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Bbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ under addition  does not satisfy your condition (see Edit below) there is no semigroup $S$ that does.

Indeed, if $S$ contains an idempotent $e=e^2$ then $\{e\}S=\{e\} eS$ in $Q_S$, hence $S=eS$, so $e$ is a left identity element. Similarly $e$ is a right identity element, so $e$ is the identity element in $S$. But then $SS=S=\{e\}S$ in $Q_S$, so $S=\{e\}$, a contradiction.

Thus $S$ does not contain idempotents. But then $S$ contains an infinite cyclic subsemigroup $C$ which is isomorphic to the additive semigroup $\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, a contradiction  because $Q_C\le Q_S$.

**Edit: ** The semigroup  $Q_{\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\}}$ does not satisfy the cancelation property as @Simon noticed:
$$\{2\}+2(\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\})=2(\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\})+2(\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\})$$ but $$\{2\}\ne 2(\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in S$ and let $a^+ = \{a^n \mid n > 0\}$ be the subsemigroup of $S$ generated by $a$. Since $aa^+ = a^+a^+$, one gets $a = a^+$ by right cancellation. Thus $a = a^2$ and $S$ is an idempotent semigroup. Furthermore, $aS = aaS$ implies $S = aS$ by left cancellation.
Consequently, $SS = \bigcup_{x \in S} xS = S = aS$, whence $S = a$ by right cancellation. Thus $S$ is the trivial semigroup.

Answer (score -1):

The set of positive integers under addition forms a cancellative semigroup, this is clearly not a group embeddable semigroup.